# Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV 8 and Return of the Dragon Lords

Tags: yu-gi-oh

A friend of mine is building a Horus the Black Flame Dragon deck. He had a question related to [Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV 8](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Horus_the_Black_Flame_Dragon_LV8).

This card cannot be Normal Summoned/Set. This card cannot be special summoned except by the effect of [Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV 6](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Horus_the_Black_Flame_Dragon_LV6). As long as this card remains face up on the field, you can negate the activation of any spell cards and destroy them.

So say he successfully summoned LV 8 and it gets in the graveyard. Can he still use [Return of the Dragon Lords](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Dragon_Lords) to resurrect it from the Graveyard?

Comment: Good question, the key part is the "cannot be SS except by"... included an answer to clarify

Answer (score 2):

> Can he still use Return of the Dragon Lords to resurrect it from the Graveyard?

**No.**

Horus lvl 8 specifically indicates:

> This card cannot be special summoned **except by** the effect of "Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV 6".

So the only way you can special summon it is with Horus lvl 6; once dead you can't bring it back with other cards.

---

On a further note, there are some cards that you can bring back after they are destroyed. If you see any card that says *"Must be **first** special summoned by..."*, then those cards you can bring back after they die, but only if the first time you special summoned them was as the card specifies. After that you can repeatedly special summon it by other means.

One example is the famous [Black Luster Soldier - Envoy of the Beginning](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Luster_Soldier_-_Envoy_of_the_Beginning):

> Cannot be Normal Summoned/Set. **Must first be Special Summoned (from your hand) by** banishing 1 LIGHT and 1 DARK monster from your Graveyard. [...]

This means you must first banish one light and dark monsters to summon BLS, but after that *successful* summon you can special summon it by other means (like [Call of the Haunted](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Haunted)).

**Edit:** As per @Kitsunezeta suggestion, one card that your friend could use to do ignore that special summon condition is [Level Up!]:

> Send 1 face-up "LV" monster you control to the Graveyard; Special Summon 1 monster from your hand or Deck that is listed in the sent monster's text, **ignoring its Summoning conditions**.

Of course this enables to pull Horus from the deck or hand, so still if it's destroyed its gone for good.

Comment: It's worth noting that Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV 8 CAN in fact be Special Summoned by other cards, the two that I am aware of are the spell cards "Level Modulation" (if it is in the graveyard) and "Level Up!" (if it is in your hand or deck and the LV 6 card is on the field). Both of those cards include the phrase "Ignoring the Summoning Conditions", which ignores the restriction on how it can be special summoned. In the case of "Level Up!", the LV 6 card's effect doesn't occur as it is sent to the graveyard as a COST, not an EFFECT.

Comment: @Kitsunezeta indeed, but OP asked for another card, and yes those you suggest are valid options, and specific support cards for the LVL archetypes. Still what you say is a good alternative for OP's friend, updating my answer in a moment.to include your valuable suggestions :)

Comment: The only other catch is a fine-print UDE ruling on Level Modulation, which requires that, for cards that state a specific method (like Horus BFD LV 8), it must have been SS'd by that method first in order to be SS'd from the graveyard... which makes Level Modulation less useful in the long run (if it was SS'd by "Level Up!", it can't be SS'd by "Level Modulation") [I did not know about that particular bit of fine print before my previous comment.]

Comment: @Kitsunezeta it's ok we can't know all errata. Seems like that may have been implemented to prevent overpowered monsters like Horus 8 from being brought back so easily.

Comment: nomi monsters like Horus use the phrase 'except by' while semi-nomi sometimes use the phrase 'only by'. One might view that as a distinction without a difference but in the world of Yugioh they would be wrong. https://yugiohblog.konami.com/articles/?p=1099